# Java logging.properties file only print specific logger

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am using a .jar file and read from a `logging.properties` file.

This is the command I use to start the application ( a proxy application )

`java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar CMDHL7Proxy_v0.7.jar`

I already configured the file `logging.properties` to log to a file.

This is the content of my `logging.properties` file:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /opt/log/Proxy_%u_%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Facility specific properties. Provides extra control for each logger.
# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE messages:
com.xyz.foo.level = SEVERE
ca.uhn.log.HapiLogImpl = OFF
au.id.czapski.hl7.SimpleForwardApplicaiton = ALL
```

If I look into the `.log` file then I see log messages from:

`Jan 28, 2019 5:48:31 PM ca.uhn.log.HapiLogImpl info 
<.... logged content .... > 
<.... logged content .... >`

and

`Jan 28, 2019 5:29:34 PM au.id.czapski.hl7.SimpleForwardApplicaiton processMessage
<.... logged content .... > 
<.... logged content .... >`

My Goal is to **only get messages from** this logger **"au.id.czapski.hl7.SimpleForwardApplicaiton"**

My understanding tells me the the last two lines in my `logging.properties` file should tell java to not log anything from the first logger but everything from the second logger.

I also tried setting different values with `.level` and `java.util.logging.FileHandler.level` but to set `java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=processMessage` did result in a configuration error.

Can someone help me to achieve my desired behavior by only modifying the `logging.properties` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like:

1. You forgot to include '.level' when setting the level of a logger.
2. You misspelled 'SimpleForwardApplicaiton'.  Does that match the logger name?
3. You didn't turn off all of the other loggers. This only works for loggers that have been created by code.

Try setting the root logger to OFF and only turning on logger you want to see

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /opt/log/Proxy_%u_%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

.level=OFF
au.id.czapski.hl7.SimpleForwardApplicaiton.level = ALL
au.id.czapski.hl7.SimpleForwardApplication.level = ALL
```

Comment: Hi the typo is in the source code itself so the logger name was correct. Your answer works